How do I calculate the minimum amount when placing an order on binance futures testnet-api using ccxt?
I see that on testnet interface from binance you are not allowed to place any price you want. It has specific values for each symbol. For example BTC/USDT has the min value of 0.002.
Can anyone explain how this value is calculated?
I saw several responses on stackoverflow but none of them did not helped me to achieve this value.
The ideea was that min amount would be calculated like this:
# Example for BTC/USDT
price = 68000  # Example price for BTC
min_notional = symbol_info['limits']['cost']['min']  # For example, this is 100

# Calculate minimum amount based on notional value
min_amount_based_on_notional = min_notional / price  # which is 0.0014925373134328358

# Ensure the amount satisfies the lot size filter
min_lot_size = lot_size_filter['min']   # this is 0.001
final_min_amount = max(min_amount_based_on_notional, min_lot_size)

print(f'Minimum amount for the order: {final_min_amount}')

But running this on testnet server api (futures) gives a value below 0.002.
Is there a problem in testnet server from binance or am I doing something wrong?
